# VS Code sftp with ssh tunnel

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, sftp

is there any possibility in VS Code to connect to an sftp server using a ssh tunnel ?

In WinSCP this works fine with the following configuration:

[image]

I try to make the same in VS Code, maybe using the liximomo extension?